# Getting null values in the ASP.NET MVC Controller from checkboxes using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I want to post data to the server.  In the form, I've selected checked checkboxes and retrieve values from them.  I used the following code:

```
$(".DownloadSelected").click(function () {
    var values = [];
    var chks = $(':checkbox[name="ids"]:checked');

    $(chks).each(function (i) {
        values[i] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.post("/Documents/DownloadSelected/", { ids: values });
});
```

In controller I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadSelected(int[] ids)
{
}
```

The problem is that in controller I retrieved `null` values in `int[]ids` array.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Values in javascript code are not passed as array of int, try to parse each value as int `parseInt($(this).val());`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(".DownloadSelected").click(function () {
        var chks = $(':checkbox[name="ids"]:checked');

        var values= $(chks).each(function (i) {
           return i.val();
        });
        values.join(',');
        $.post("/Documents/DownloadSelected/", { ids: values });
    });
```

and in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadSelected(List<int> ids)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, guys, I've decide this problem using usual $.ajax() function, not $.post()

Comment: The problem was,that i must use  {traditional:true} in ajax options of $.ajax() function.

Answer (score 0):

you should define a complex type and define a property int[] .

```
public class PostModel
{
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

and in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadSelected(PostModel postModel)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your checkbox inputs in the form as follow

```
<form id="frm">
<input type="checkbox"  name="ids" value="1">
<input type="checkbox"  name="ids" value="2">
<input type="checkbox"  name="ids" value="3">
</form>
```

then post from

```
var form=$("#frm");
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "your action url here",
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); 
           }
         });
```